# IBodyModelValidator Are you missing a type mapping?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I am getting below error, what could be the reason.

I have just created one new controller, for other Controllers its working fine.

```
Error:

Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Web.Http.Validation.IBodyModelValidator", name = "(none)".

Exception occurred while: while resolving.

Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Http.Validation.IBodyModelValidator, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

-----------------------------------------------

At the time of the exception, the container was:



  Resolving System.Web.Http.Validation.IBodyModelValidator,(none)
```

And its falling at below line.

```
public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (this.Container == null)
            {
                throw new ObjectDisposedException("this", "This scope has already been disposed.");
            }

                try
                {
                    return this.Container.Resolve(serviceType);
                }
                catch (ResolutionFailedException)
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
```

May be I am not clear with my question, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

with

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

and it worked.